# React Native Flatlist scrolling to left and right with horizontal={true}

Tags: react-native

So I have a flat list with data. Let's say my data is: `"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"`

Than I have a flat list with `horizontal={true}`. Now when I start the app I see 1 and 2 and 3 (for exmaple).

But instead of this I want to "start" on 5.

What I want:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

So that when I open the App I see 4 and 5 and 6 and I can scroll to the left to see 1  and 2 and 3 and I can scroll to the right and see 7 and 8 and 9 and 10. :) I hope you understand my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use [`scrollToIndex`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex) function of the `FlatList`.

Example:

```
const MyView = () => {
  const flatListRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {   
    flatListRef.current?.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index: 4 }); 
  }, [])

  return (
    <FlatList  
       {/* ... */}
       ref={flatListRef}
    />
  );
}
```

Centering the "5" view on the screen would require you to calculate and pass `viewOffset` parameter to `scrollToIndex`. Calculation would involve accounting for container width and the total size of scrollable content, and this is too tricky to work out in an answer, since there is a number of edge cases to consider.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now I have a point to start from :)